# after the for loop there's no {} brace for (i=0; s[i]>='0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)

Tags: c

I am learning chapter 2: types, operators and expressions of "The C programming language Edition 2", and encounter such a snippet of code:

```
/* atoi: convert s to integer */
int atoi(char s[]) {
    int i, n;

    n = 0;
    for (i=0; s[i]>='0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');

}
```

What's puzzle me is that `n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');` is not enbraced within `{}`, I assume it should be

```
/* atoi: convert s to integer */
int atoi(char s[]) {
    int i, n;

    n = 0;
    for (i=0; s[i]>='0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i) {
        n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    }

}
```

What's the problem with my assumption?

Comment: `{}` are optional if the loop body is a single line

Comment: And right to the SO. Learn more a bit.

Comment: @soon Not single line, a single *statement*.

Comment: Following the `for` statement comes 1 statement or a block of statements. A block of statements is enclosed in `{` and `}` and counts as 1 statement. An empty statement ("do nothing") is denoted by `;` and is also considered 1 statement.

Comment: Though they are optional I suggest to always use braces in `for` loop bodies. This prevents silly bugs when you later want to add another statement, not noticing the missing braces. If I see a `for` loop without braces in code of peer devs, I immediately ask myself if they have such a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for the `for` loop can be read in 6.8.5 Iteration statements:

> ```
> for ( expression_opt ; expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
> for ( declaration expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
> ```

In turn, a `statement` is (6.8 Statements and blocks):

> ```
> statement:
>     labeled-statement
>     compound-statement
>     expression-statement
>     selection-statement
>     iteration-statement
>     jump-statement
> ```

---

The `compound-statement` is the one you are using when you write

```
for (i=0; s[i]>='0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i) {
    n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
}
```

However, when you write:

```
for (i=0; s[i]>='0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
    n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
```

You are using an `expression-statement`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just one statement in a loop the braces are optional. If you have more than one statement you must put braces.

Comment: If you could reference the standard here, this could be considered an answer. Otherwise it is no more than a comment.